# Run from the ballerina composer fails for port 5010

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

Running a simple example within the ballerina composer fails with the following exception.

```
[2018-06-13 11:01:29,024] ERROR {org.ballerinalang.launcher.Main} - failed to connect to localhost:5010 
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to connect to localhost:5010
    at org.ballerinalang.logging.BLogManager.setHttpTraceLogHandler(BLogManager.java:163)
    at org.ballerinalang.logging.BLogManager.loadUserProvidedLogConfiguration(BLogManager.java:111)
    at org.ballerinalang.launcher.LauncherUtils.loadConfigurations(LauncherUtils.java:313)
    at org.ballerinalang.launcher.LauncherUtils.runProgram(LauncherUtils.java:79)
    at org.ballerinalang.launcher.Main$RunCmd.execute(Main.java:256)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)
    at org.ballerinalang.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.SocketHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.ballerinalang.logging.BLogManager.setHttpTraceLogHandler(BLogManager.java:157)
    ... 6 more
```

Because manual start from the console with `ballerina run hello-world.bal` does work without issues.

**What is the issue here when running from the composer?**

- Environment: ballerina-0.970.1, Windows 10, Java 8

Comment: Are you running with tracing enabled ? How are you starting up the service ? Any arguments you are passing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with ballerina composer. This is reported [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/8695) 
. Fix will be available for next ballerina public release which is due today. Or you can try latest [ballerina nightly build](https://ballerina.io/downloads/).